# Remotely access sleeping MacBook over internet

Tags: windows, mac, remote-desktop, wake-on-lan

What's the best way to remotely access my sleeping MacBook over the Internet on a windows computer that is not on the same network? (Home MacBook, windows work computer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a Mac expert, and while Wake-on-LAN is difficult to do remotely, it appears that there are efforts to overcome this. I will let you read these links, and see if you can either make it work, or at least get to a point where you can ask further questions.

This might be the most important link, by doing port forwarding on your router of port 9, and using this site, it claims to able to wake your computer (it may be this simple):

http://www.dslreports.com/wakeup

For more on Wake-on-LAN and its requirements, read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Sleep_Proxy_Service_(Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy)

For more Apple-specific links, read this:

http://www.tuaw.com/2009/08/29/snow-leopard-extends-wake-on-lan-feature-if-your-config-is-ri/

http://www.macworld.com/article/140422/2009/05/wakeonlan.html

I would like to be more help, but like I said, I am not a Mac guy, so I do not have one to test with as I do with most of my answers here.

Comment: Ooh, very good! I'm gonna try some of that stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If its sleeping, you can't do it...

You can wake it though:

> Modern Mac hardware features integrated WoL functionality, controlled via the OS X System Preferences Energy Saver panel, in the Options tab. Marking the Wake for Ethernet network administrator access checkbox enables Wake-on-LAN.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Sleep_Proxy_Service_(Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy)) also for more information.

Comment: Not even with wake-on-LAN or something similar?

Comment: Sleep = computer is basically off, but the RAM is still powered. You can't do anything without waking it.

Comment: Is there a way to remotely wake it? :-)

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN). There may be something, but never heard of it before.

Comment: @soandos You might want to check out the stuff I found. I thought as you did, but it might not be so clear.

Comment: @KCotreau I edited my answer, and have two of the same sources even.